# C# - не удаляется файл после чтения

Tags: c#

Помогите пожалуйста. Не могу удалить файл после того как выполнил чтение файла.Чтение файла в программе:

```
db = new SQLiteConnection("Data Source = Subjects/" + DBName + ".db; Version = 3");
db.Open();
cmd = db.CreateCommand();
cmd.CommandText = "select name from sqlite_master where type = 'table'";
SQReader = cmd.ExecuteReader();

for (int i = 0; SQReader.Read(); i++)
{
   ChaptersList[i] += SQReader["name"];
   CBox1.Items.Add(ChaptersList[i]);
}
db.Close();
```

Удаление файла:

```
FileInfo fi = new FileInfo("Subjects/" + LBSubjects.SelectedItem + ".db");
fi.Delete();
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: код вставляйте текстом, а не картинкой. И приведите также код чтения файла, а не только удаления

Comment: db = new SQLiteConnection("Data Source = Subjects/" + DBName + ".db; Version = 3");
            db.Open();
            cmd = db.CreateCommand();
            cmd.CommandText = "select name from sqlite_master where type = 'table'";
            SQReader = cmd.ExecuteReader();

            for (int i = 0; SQReader.Read(); i++)
            {
                ChaptersList[i] += SQReader["name"];
                CBox1.Items.Add(ChaptersList[i]);
            }
            db.Close();

Comment: `SQReader.Close();`

Comment: Не помогает. Файл по прежнему используется другим процессом

Comment: Попробуйте оставить только `db.Open();` и `db.Close();` - без чтения. Удаляется? А потом и это уберите. Удаляется?

Comment: И еще. Вы уверены, что это тот же самый файл?

Comment: SQReader = cmd.ExecuteReader();

            for (int i = 0; SQReader.Read(); i++)
            {
                ChaptersList[i] += SQReader["name"];
                CBox1.Items.Add(ChaptersList[i]);
            }
            SQReader.Close();    закомментировав этот блок все удалялось

Comment: Читаю файл я через Form1 а удаляю через Form2

Answer (score 0):

Вам надо удалять объект `SQLConnection` после каждой операции. Почему? Потому что все объекты-обертки для работы с базой данных созданы как одноразовые обертки(для одного действия). 
Используйте

```
using (var db = new SQLiteConnection)
{
    using (var command = new SQLiteCommand())
    {
    }
}`
```

Так объекты `db` и `command` будут удалены после использования. Да, и `SQLReader.Close()` закрывает `Connection` только для ввода команд, но при этом не разрывает связь `Connection`. Поэтому и не получается удалить файл (он используется, просто-напросто).